# How can I neither immediately deny entry or admit a new participant in Google Meet?

Tags: google-meet

From time to time, I would like to wait before clicking on deny entry or admit for a new participant in Google Meet. However, waiting prevents me from unmute/mute the microphone/camera. Is there a way around it?

[image]